# how to convert html and css to a pdf file in android?

Tags: android, html, css, pdf-generation, itext

I have a requirement where by I need to convert a complex `HTML` file that has `CSS` styles into a `PDF` file in an Android app. I tried using `IText` library for Android but it is not able to interpret the `CSS` styles and some of the tags. I have searched a lot, and haven't been able to find a library that meets my requirement.

my function createpdf

```
public static void createPdf(final String pdfName, final String html) {

    try {
        String outpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + pdfName;
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(outpath));

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        document.open();
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
        htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(html));
        document.close();
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("error", "testPdf: " + e);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        Log.d("error", "testPdf: " + e);
    }


}
```

sample HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style media="all">
      body,html {
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .container {
        position: relative;
        width:1020px;
        margin:20px auto 0 auto;
      }
      .box {
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background: #E4DFEC;
        border:2px solid #000;
      }
      .box_panel {
        margin:10px 0;
      }
      .box span {
        width: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        font:bold 11px/11px 'Calibri',sans-serif;
        color:#000;
      }
      .labels {
        margin: 5px 0;
        margin-right:40px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0;
      }
      .input {
        border:1px solid #000;
        background: #fff;
        padding:4px 3px;
        font:11px/20px 'Calibri',sans-serif;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="box_panel">

        <div class="box">
          <div class="labels"><span>Test1 </span><span class="input w200">%test%</span></div>
          <div class="labels"><span>Test2 </span><span class="input w200">%test%</span></div>
          <div class="labels"><span>Test3: </span><span class="input w100">%test%</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Or with the result? Do you have questions?

Comment: how to html to pdf file

Comment: You have not answered any of my questions. You are not serious.

Comment: You use `HTMLWorker` in your code. Please don't. It's deprecated and it's only very basic, more like a proof of concept. You should use `XMLWorker` instead.